# How to delay pygame.key.get_pressed()?

Tags: python, pygame

I haven't been able to find a straightforward answer.

`key.set_repeat()` works for `KEYDOWN` events, but not for `key.get_pressed()`:

```
import sys, pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
Clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.set_mode((200, 100))

pygame.key.set_repeat(1, 500)

while True:

    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_UP]:
        print('up!')

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                print('down!')

    Clock.tick(30)
```

Even the slightest tap on UP explodes into at least a few up!s, only down!s are delayed. I want to use `key.get_pressed()` since it conveniently handles multiple inputs. Do I have to work around it with some sorta tick counter? Alternatively, is there a way to handle multiple `KEYDOWN` events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't mess around with `key.set_repeat()` if you don't have to.

Simply use `key.get_pressed()` to check for keys that are pressed and where keeping that key pressed down has a meaning to you, e.g. something like *move left while `K_LEFT` is pressed*.

Use `event.get()` / `KEYDOWN` when you're interessed in a single key press, e.g. something like *pressing `K_P` pauses the game*.

If you mess around with `key.set_repeat()`, e.g. set the delay to low, you won't be able to recognize a single key stroke, since every key stroke will create multiple `KEYDOWN` events.

To handle multiple `KEYDOWN` events, just check for the relevant events. Every key stroke will generate a `KEYDOWN` event, so you can simple check e.g.:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_DOWN:
            print('down!')
        elif event.key == K_UP:
            print('up!')
```

That will of course print `up!`/`down!` multiple times if the user keeps pressing the keys.

The golden rule is: If you're interessted in the `KEYDOWN` and the `KEYUP` event of a single key, better use `key.get_pressed()` instead.

---

> Even the slightest tap on UP explodes into at least a few up!s, only down!s are delayed

That's because the event system and `key.get_pressed()` are totally different. If you get pressing `K_UP` over multiple frames, for each frame `'up!'` is printed because the key is pressed down in every frame. `key.get_pressed()` simple returns which keys are pressed at the moment you call this function. In other words: you can't "delay" it.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation, pygame's documentation was a little unclear on this point, at least for a layman like me.